# webdriver-manager getting error as executable

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I have a python script which uses `ChromeDriverManager().install()` for getting the latest chromedriver.

A snippet of the code:

```
def get_location():
    exe_path = "C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"

    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.binary_location = exe_path

    service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Everything works fine when run using the `main.py` script, no error. But when I convert the python file, `main.py` to an executable, `main.exe` using `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py` the **webdriver manager shows error on the ChromeDriverManager().install() line**.

The error is this:

[image]

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the `exe_path`?  You don't know where another user might have chosen to install that.

Comment: Don't worry the file has a settings.json file which the user can modify. This code is just a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = str(logging.NOTSET)
os.environ['WDM_PROGRESS_BAR'] = str(0)
```

Add these lines at the beginning of your function. This disables Webdriver-manager logs. The error is caused by not having a console to view the logs.